# How to send custom graph data to MCStats every hour?

Tags: java, bukkit, mcstats

I have been working on a plugin and have gotten some really interesting data with it, I am trying to add a custom graph and have succeeded on getting the graph to appear with the name I set in code on [MCStats](http://mcstats.org/plugin/DenseOres).

My plugin is [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/dense-ores.10087/) and recreates the Dense Ores Mod.

I would like to send block mined data on an hourly basis. This is what I have in my `onEnable` so far:

```
try {
    Metrics metrics = new Metrics(this);
    Graph blocksMinedGraph = metrics.createGraph("Extra items from blocks");
    blocksMinedGraph.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter("Coal Ore") {
        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return coalMined;
        }
    });
    blocksMinedGraph.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter("Iron Ore") {
        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return ironMined;
        }
    });
    metrics.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    getLogger().info(ANSI_RED + "Metrics have been unable to load for: DenseOres" + ANSI_RESET);
}
```

This has successfully created a new graph on my MCStats page called 'Extra items from blocks' although I have been unable to populate it thus far. I have tried but cannot work out how to send the data.

Connected to this question, when sending the data, will I have to keep a count of the values in a file somewhere so they persist between reloads and server restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appear to have solved it by placing the `blocksMinedGraph.addPlotter(...)` parts in an async repeating task.

Here is the code with the repeating task in place, the graphs on MCStats take forever to update though.

```
try {
    Metrics metrics = new Metrics(this);
    if (!metrics.isOptOut()) {
        final Graph blocksMinedGraph = metrics.createGraph("Extra items from blocks (Since v2.3)");
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimerAsynchronously(this, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getLogger().info("Graph data sent");
                blocksMinedGraph.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter("Coal Ore") {
                    @Override
                    public int getValue() {
                        return coalMined;
                    }
                });
                blocksMinedGraph.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter("Iron Ore") {
                    @Override
                    public int getValue() {
                        return ironMined;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, DELAY, INCREMENT);
        getLogger().info("Metrics started");
        metrics.start();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    getLogger().info(ANSI_RED + "Metrics have been unable to load for: DenseOres" + ANSI_RESET);
}
```